# Suggest regular expression

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

Can some one suggest regular expression for below text

> **Signature**
>
> text text some more text
>
> text
>
> ...
>
> text **)**

I tried `Signature\n.*\)` but this only works for

> **Signature**
>   text )

Basically an expression which starts with a given text, allows multiple new lines, and ends with `)`.

Thanks

Comment: There is new lines between text and text ..dont know why it wrapped :(

Comment: Please accept answers from your existing questions by clicking on the checkbox to the left of the answer that's been the most helpful to you. Thanks!

Comment: here flex means gnu lexical analyzer (as in lex and yacc) not adobe flash

Comment: It worked ..just for flex use signature[^)]*\) ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `.` doesn't match new-lined by default.

A simple option is:

```
/signature[^)]*\)/i
```

`[^)]*` will match all characters besides `)`.

I'm not sure if you have a Dot-All flag in flex. In JavaScript the `/s` flag is missing, and the common work around is:

```
/signature[\s\S]*?\)/i
```

In this case, you probably want to use a lazy quantifier, `*?`, so you match until the first `)`, and not the last.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var pattern:RegExp = /^Signature.+\\)/m;
```

Comment: Not familiar with Flex's regex API, but shouldn't that be the `s` flag instead of the `m` flag? And is the double backslash necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex

\bSignature[\s\S]*?[)]

This regex will first look at Signature, followed by any character which includes alphanumeric characters, \n , etc followed by )

Answer (score 0):

Flex supports negated character classes, so you could do:

```
/* definition section */

%%

Signature[^)]*\) { /* custom code */ }

%%

/* user subroutines */
```